# GTK# theme for portable mono application

Tags: mono, xamarin, gtk, gtk#

Why the same application looks different while it started from Visual Studio or Xamarin Studio or as normal application?

From VS:

[image: From Visual Studio]

From Xamarin Studio:

[image: From Xamarin Studio]

As normal application:

[image: Normal]

It looks like different theme is applying for all of these cases.

And setting

```
 Rc.AddDefaultFile("gtkrc");
 Rc.Parse("gtkrc");
```

has no effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could not see the VS and normal images.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be of any help, but I've run into this many times before.  What I have typically done is to explicitly set the background colors, fonts, button sizes, etc, etc. directly in the code.  It isn't 100% perfect, but it helps to avoid some of the differences when running on different platforms.  I'm basically forcing it to look one way or another and limiting outside influence.  Again, not even close to 100% perfect but it's better than nothing, I guess.  Another option is to take a look at [XWT](https://github.com/mono/xwt) or [Eto Forms](https://github.com/picoe/Eto).  With these toolkits you can create GUIs that render the native widgets.